# Live in MN and my 1900 home has basement walls that are crumbling and falling off, how do I correct this?

Tags: water, repair, walls, basement

Basement wall had been slowly crumbling and falling since I moved in. It is an older 1900 basement, not sure what was used to cover. I had a lot of issues with water coming in when I first moved in roughly 10 yrs ago. How do I remove and replace?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the visible part of the basement wall look like from outside? I'd expect something like fieldstone for that era, in which case this might just be rather thick parging (cement or plaster) to make the inside flat.

Comment: Zooming into the picture, it looks like concrete blocks behind plasterwork. Is that the case?

Comment: I have added a picture from the outside. I am not entirely sure what it is.

Comment: It's possible the structure is fine and the cosmetic surface skim coat is flaking off.   That is what @UnhandledExcepSean is asking.

Comment: I won’t know more until I remove the crumbling layer. But what you say about the thick parging may be accurate. Does that need to be reapplied?

Answer (score 0):

Buildings of this age often had a layer of horsehair plaster on the inside of brick foundations. It's intended to forms a system with the lime mortar, helping to control moisture levels so the mortar self-heals any damage.

However, in many buildings, that plaster is largely or completely gone, and they're still standing. My own house, built some time before 1890, is missing most of that layer, and no contractor has ever suggested I replace it (though I was warned that modern mortars were incompatible with the old case-hardened bricks).

I haven't researched it farther. But there are a number of websites about maintaining old and/or historic houses; I'm sure that one of them could tell you how to properly repair this.